# HttpClient in a loop

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache HttpClient to invoke an API inside a batch (STANDALONE) JAVA program.
Below is the code

```java
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setIntParameter("http.connection.timeout",5000);
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8080/endpoint");

for (String strRequest:listA) {
    postMethod.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(strRequest,"application/json","UTF-8"));
    postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
    if (statusCode !=200) {
        responseBodyStr = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } else {
        responseBodyStr = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
    }
    System.out.println(responseBodyStr);
}
```

On the second iteration, I get a 400 (Socket timeout) error.
Is there any way to reset the `httpClient` here, so I can reuse the same object. It will also help with my unit testing. This is the simplified version of the code. Actual code has lot of processing based on the response received from the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpClient = null;

PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8080/endpoint");

for (String strRequest:listA) {
   httpClient = new HttpClient();
   httpClient.getParams().setIntParameter("http.connection.timeout",5000);
        postMethod.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(strRequest,"application/json","UTF-8"));
        postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        if (statusCode !=200) {
            responseBodyStr = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        } else {
            responseBodyStr = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }
        System.out.println(responseBodyStr);
}
```

Can you please try this.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new `PostMethod` per iteration, rather than a new `HttpClient`, no?